# NPE when declare a layout from a customized view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I have a class which extends `View`, and inside that class, at a specific point, I want to display text with a small icon beside it.

To achieve this, I created an XML layout as shown below, and inside the class that extends `View` I define the layout so its contents appear on the screen, but the App crashes with a NullPointerException.

Please let me know how to solve it.

***Update_1***:

I have initialized the `LayoutInflater` in `onsizeChanged()` as follows but when I run the App, nothing appears.

**Initialization in onSizechanged**:

```
void  onsizechanged() {                                 
Layoutinflater mlayoutinf = LayoutInflater.from(this.mcontext;  
View mview = mLayoutInf.inflate(R.id.confMSG_Yes,null);
this.tv = (textview) mView.findViewById(R.id.confMSG_Yes) 
}

 ontouchevent(){                                                       
 ....
 ....
 showconfirmation()

 }
 showconfirmation() {                                              

 this.tv.settext("some text");

 }
```

**xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/rL01_ConfMSG"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/confMSG_Header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/confMSG_Header"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/rL02_ConfMSG"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/confMSG_Yes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:drawableRight="@drawable/accept"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Java File**

```
private void showConfirmation() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stubfin 

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.confMSG_Yes);
    tv.setText("some text");
}
```

Comment: As @gmale mentioned, you should be inflating your layout XML in the view constructor, not in onSizechanged.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your view isn't inflating this layout. `this.findViewById` essentially searches through the layout that was inflated for `this` view.

You may need to add a line like the following to your constructor for the view (note: [inflate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#inflate(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.view.ViewGroup)) is a static method inside the `View` class):

```
inflate( context, R.layout.view_name_of_your_layout_file, this );
```

Comment: i am calling the above mentioned method from ontouchevent()

Comment: have you inflated your layout during the construction of your view? If not, doing so, via the code above, would fix your problem.

Comment: you should consider inflating your layout elsewhere. It's not common to do so in onSizeChanged–that's typically where you'd want to put logic concerned with changes to width and height, rather than logic to initialize your view. Initialization is better suited for a constructor like in [this example from the Google IO app](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/MessageCardView.java#L67).

Answer (score 0):

From where are you calling `showConfirmation()`? It's possible that you're calling it before the layout has been inflated.

When you initialize your view, inflate it from your XML and return a reference to the view:

> View view = inflate(getContext(), R.layout.layout_id, null);

Then get a reference to your TextView:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.confMSG_Yes);
```